# publishing windows phone 7 game - test case 5.2.4 back button

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, publishing

Ive been reading from several sources, and now Im more confused then ever.

So my app failed the test because I was exiting the game each time I clicked the back button.

So I "fixed" it to go always to the menu which is always the previous screen for coincidence...

the problem is that now I submmited the app like this...

When pressing back button in the menu, nothing will happen... because im already in the menu...

What If I add a pause screen in the game how is the back button is suppose to behave?

Press once -> go to pause 
Press again will go back to the game? or go to the menu?

the problem is... if this is true I wont have a way to go back to the menu, if i want to quit the game...

So I need to make a menu with only button one "exit" button to go back to the menu?

my question is... How is the back button suppose to behave?

Comment: StackOverflow is designed to work around "one question per post", so that an answer can be selected. Also, regarding your #1, you need to ask Microsoft about their submission policies; we're [not Customer Support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579).

Comment: #1, just code it correctly so when the user is at the menu, you let them leave. YOU showed the menu, just as easily you could set a flag and check it inside the handler of the back button.

Comment: and #2 is up to you - most likely, the user doesn't expect the game to continue when they press back and see the menu - that said, press back IS pause. on your menu, "if game is running, change the 'Play Game' button to read 'Return to Game'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like theres no way to stop submission for now.
The back button is suppose to go back to the menu, or pause the game, but if you are in the menu you have to quit the application.

Also, if you choose to pause the game, you have to make a menu that allows you to go back to the game or quit to the main menu which is more complicated.

These tests should be automatic...